# PHP open a running app in multiple tabs in same browser

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php application in which I scrape a website and get all of the links present in the site. While I am running the scraper in a tab of a browser and open the app in the other tab of the same browser, it keeps loading until the other tab processing(running **scraper**) is complete.

I have tried using ajax in this case i.e. I send the request through ajax post to find the links, but it is not effecting.

Any kind of help and guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Any code to share? Do you use sessions?

Comment: I am not sure which code should I share. Yes, I am using sessions to store the urls of the site I am scrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably caused by the session lock.  If your multiple connections (tabs) require the same session, you can't.

If they could be independent, then you would have to pass a session id in the URL to identify which tab is communicating with the server.

Note that the web server may also have restrictions configured on the number of simultaneous sessions from the same IP.